# Errors when try to render a Section List

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to render a `SectionList`, but it is returning three errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
The above error occurred in the <VirtualizedSectionList> component:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Code data of `SectionList`:

```
const {data, esporte, quantidadeTimes} = route.params;
function embaralhar(array) {
for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
  [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
}
}
function separarTimes(arr, tamanho) {
  var novoArray = [];
  var i = 0;
  var numeroTime = 1;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    novoArray.push({title: "Time "+ numeroTime, nomes: arr.slice(i, i + tamanho), });
    numeroTime += 1;
    i += tamanho;
  }
  return novoArray;
}
const dataEmbaralhada = embaralhar(data);
const timesSeparados = separarTimes(dataEmbaralhada, Math.trunc(data.length/quantidadeTimes))
```

Example `timesSeparados`:

```
[
  {
    title: "Time 1",
    nomes: [
      {
        nome: "Nome1",
        nivelId: 4,
        isGoleiro: false,
        id: 0
      },
      {
        nome: "Nome2",
        nivelId: 0,
        isGoleiro: false,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        nome: "Nome3",
        nivelId: 2,
        isGoleiro: true,
        id: 2
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Time 2",
    nomes: [
      {
        nome: "Nome1",
        nivelId: 4,
        isGoleiro: false,
        id: 0
      },
      {
        nome: "Nome2",
        nivelId: 0,
        isGoleiro: false,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        nome: "Nome3",
        nivelId: 2,
        isGoleiro: true,
        id: 2
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Code `SectionList`:

```
<ListaNomes
  renderItem={renderItem}
  renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
  )}
  sections={timesSeparados}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
/>
```

Code render item:

```
const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <NomeItemContainer>
          <Nome>
              {item.nomes.nome}
          </Nome>
          <Infos>
              <Nivel>
                  {item.nomes.nivelId}
              </Nivel>
              {
                item.nomes.goleiro === true
                ? <MaterialIcons name="pan-tool" size={20} color="white" style={{paddingRight: 5}}/>
                : <Nome></Nome>
              }
          </Infos>
      </NomeItemContainer>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass an array of data in this line

```
const dataEmbaralhada = embaralhar(data);
```

Which expects an array, but in `SectionList`

`const {data, esporte, quantidadeTimes} = route.params;`

you have destructured `data` that may not be present in `route.params`,which gets passed in the `embaralhar` function as an `undefined`, then you are trying to loop through that `undefined` in the `embaralhar` function which I assume is throwing `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. Also another reason could be nothing is returned from `embaralhar`. As `separarTimes` is also dependent on `data` it will also break for same reason. Furthermore according to my knowledge it's not possible to pass an array in the `route.params` nor is a good idea to do so. Try to extract data in other means. Like as `props` or using `context API`. Hopefully that helps. Try this.

Comment: Well, I tested both functions (embaralhar and separarTimes) at console.log, and both worked.

Comment: Did you return the array from `embaralhar` function

Answer (score 0):

you are reading

```js
const dataEmbaralhada = embaralhar(data);
```

but your `embaralhar` function returns nothing